# refine, average, round data python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, average

I have a large dataset (see example format below) and I need to do the follow thinks:

1. identify the repeated values that appear on columns 1,2,5 - if the all repeated then I need to remove redundant rows and average the value in column 8 (this is successful with the code I will post -
2. after step one, I want to round the values on columns 1,2 to whole number (no decimals)
3. I want to reintroduce columns 3, 4, 6 and 7 -
   columns 3, 6, and 7 need to have a specific value I will dictate (e.g. 3 should be all 0, 6 all 1, and column 7 all 1) (similar to input file)
   column 4 needs to increase by one, based on number of different values on column 4) (similar to input file

here is a sample input file: data (name of the file)

```
564991.15   7371277.89  0   1   1530    1   1   16.0225
564991.15   7371277.89  0   1   8250    1   1   14.4405
564991.15   7371277.89  0   2   1530    1   1   14.8637
564991.15   7371277.89  0   2   8250    1   1   14.8918
564991.17   7371277.89  0   3   1530    1   1   16.0002
564991.17   7371277.89  0   3   8250    1   1   15.4333
564991.04   7371276.76  0   4   1530    1   1   14.73
564991.04   7371276.76  0   4   8250    1   1   15.6138
564991.04   7371276.76  0   5   1530    1   1   16.2453
564991.04   7371276.76  0   5   8250    1   1   15.6138
```

and here is the code I have up to know (currently I supplement in calc)

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
datadirectory = '/media/data'
os.chdir = 'datadirectory'
df = pd.read_csv('/media/data/data.dat')
sorted_data = df.groupby(["X.1","X.2","X.5"])["X.8"].mean().reset_index()
tuple_data = [tuple(x) for x in sorted_data.values]
datas = np.asarray(tuple_data)
np.savetxt('sorted_data_rounded.dat', datas, fmt='%s', delimiter='\t')
```

but his gives me only the 4 columns, and no rounded data....

Answer (score 2):

It could be slightly faster to add a half and cast [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) `int`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.dat', header=None, sep='\s+')

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
           0           1  2  3     4  5  6        7
0  564991.15  7371277.89  0  1  1530  1  1  16.0225
1  564991.15  7371277.89  0  1  8250  1  1  14.4405
2  564991.15  7371277.89  0  2  1530  1  1  14.8637
3  564991.15  7371277.89  0  2  8250  1  1  14.8918
4  564991.17  7371277.89  0  3  1530  1  1  16.0002
5  564991.17  7371277.89  0  3  8250  1  1  15.4333
6  564991.04  7371276.76  0  4  1530  1  1  14.7300
7  564991.04  7371276.76  0  4  8250  1  1  15.6138
8  564991.04  7371276.76  0  5  1530  1  1  16.2453
9  564991.04  7371276.76  0  5  8250  1  1  15.6138

df1 = df.groupby([0, 1, 4])[7].mean().reset_index()
df1['ints'] = (df1[7] + 0.5).astype(int)

In [5]: df1
Out[5]: 
           0           1     4         7  ints
0  564991.04  7371276.76  1530  15.48765    15
1  564991.04  7371276.76  8250  15.61380    16
2  564991.15  7371277.89  1530  15.44310    15
3  564991.15  7371277.89  8250  14.66615    15
4  564991.17  7371277.89  1530  16.00020    16
5  564991.17  7371277.89  8250  15.43330    15
```

*Note: you can save a DataFrame using the DataFrame method [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv).*

Comment: thanks - this was a big help, I updated the code, and I am almost there - I just need to get the desired order (I can always do it with re-arranging the numpy array but I guess using pandas is more efficient)

Comment: and I think I might moved ahead abit - I will post the code when I am back in the office...... got to move now

Answer (score 1):

Use the round function()

```
x = round(number to round , number of decimal places to round the number to )
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work for the array (datas in my above example)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code does exactly what I want:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

datadirectory = '/media/DATA'
os.chdir( datadirectory)

df = pd.read_csv('/media/DATA/data.dat', sep="\\s+", header=None)
df1 = df.groupby(["X.1","X.2","X.5"])["X.8"].mean().reset_index() 
df1['X.3'] = df["X.3"]
df1['X.4']=df["X.4"]
df1['X.6']=df["X.6"]
df1['X.7']=df["X.7"]
sorted_data = df1.reindex_axis(sorted(df1.columns), axis=1)
tuple_data = [tuple(x) for x in sorted_data.values]
datas = np.asarray(tuple_data)

dfround = df
dfround['X.1'] = df["X.1"].astype(int)
dfround['X.2'] = df["X.2"].astype(int)
df2 = dfround.groupby(["X.1","X.2","X.5"])["X.8"].mean().reset_index()
df2['X.3'] = df["X.3"] #add extra columns
df2['X.4']=df["X.4"]
df2['X.6']=df["X.6"]
df2['X.7']=df["X.7"]
sorted_data2 = df2.sort_index(axis=1) #rearragne data - method 2
tuple_data2 = [tuple(x) for x in sorted_data2.values]
datas2 = np.asarray(tuple_data2)

np.savetxt('sorted_data.dat', datas, fmt='%s', delimiter='\t') #Save the data
np.savetxt('sorted_rounded_data.dat', datas2, fmt='%s', delimiter='\t') #Save   the data
print ('DONE')
```